# Position logo top right of div

Tags: html, css

Why is my logo not appearing top right of my div?

```css
.service-title {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-position: right top;
  background: orange;
  background-image: url('http://vectorlogo.biz/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/GOOGLE-VECTORLOGO-BIZ-128x128.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="service-title"><a href="/">test</a></h1>
```

Comment: It should be on the right hand side though, why is it not? Any help?

Comment: Thanks @akz, however, I'm still not sure why it's aligned left & not right.

Comment: Did you find any answers helped you fix your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
.service-title {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    padding: 1em; 
    background:orange;
    background-image:url('http://vectorlogo.biz/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/GOOGLE-VECTORLOGO-BIZ-128x128.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uq0uv2eu/10/)

Comment: Thank you! Bizarrely I had tried this with IE but it didn't work. Now it does :-)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk did you learn anything from this? Or did you just copy and paste the code? An answer that explains the solution is generally preferred, no?

Comment: @Billy Yep, I learned that the order of the declarations has an impact on the desired output.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk How? He didn't explain that at all

Answer (score 4):

It is happening because you are overriding the `background-position` property with the `background` shorthand.

### Explanation :

The background specifies :

> the concatenation of the initial values of its longhand
>   properties:
>  background-image: none
>  background-position: 0%
>   0%
>  background-size: auto auto
>  background-repeat: repeat
>   background-origin: padding-box
>  background-style: is itself a
>   shorthand, its initial value is the concatenation of its own longhand
>   properties
>  background-clip: border-box
>  background-color:
>   transparent

*(source : [mdn background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#Summary))*

So when you set `background: orange` (after `background-position` in your CSS) it implicitly gives `background-position: 0% 0%;` so it overrides your background-position statement.

### Solution :

You either need to put the `background-position` property after the `background` shorthand so it isn't overridden :

```css
.service-title {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    padding: 1em;
    background:orange;
    background-position: right top;
    background-image:url('http://vectorlogo.biz/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/GOOGLE-VECTORLOGO-BIZ-128x128.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="service-title bg-orange icon-logo-clipped"><a href="/">test</a></h1>
```

Or specify `background-color` instead of the `background` shorthand so the background-position isn't overridden.

```css
.service-title {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    padding: 1em;
    background-position: right top;
    background-color:orange;
    background-image:url('http://vectorlogo.biz/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/GOOGLE-VECTORLOGO-BIZ-128x128.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="service-title bg-orange icon-logo-clipped"><a href="/">test</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `background: orange;` line over rides the `background-position`. This is because `background` is the shorthand property that defines all the  other background properties, such as size, color, image and, of course, position. Here is the 
[MDN - shorthand `background` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) article.

Change `background` to `background-color` or just put it before `background-position`

```css
.service-title {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-position: right top;
  background-color: orange;
  background-image: url('http://vectorlogo.biz/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/GOOGLE-VECTORLOGO-BIZ-128x128.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="service-title"><a href="/">test</a></h1>
```